# Connecting to SQL Server from Visual Studio 2010 for windows phone environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am developing a mobile application for windows phone and I am using Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows phone to do so. I should be able to retrieve the data stored in a table in SQL Server. I tried using LINQ to SQL . But it can access the data present in local folder. Is there any way we can access data present in SQL server present at some other location.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly interact with a SQL Server from a Windows Phone app. The best way would be to create a service layer around your database which exposes all the operations you need.This service will be called from the mobile app. The most popular technologies for doing so on the Microsoft stack are WCF and ASP.NET Web API. Which one you choose is up to you and depends on several factors.

ref : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a653ad41-59f7-41b7-82e8-3b2c76d7dec6/sql-server-connection-for-windows-phone-8

Comment: In installed templates I do not find WCF option for me to build a WCF service application.I only have XNA and Silverlight applications opitons. Can you please tell me how to build a WCF service app so that I can use it to access database. Thanks in advance